# The title for this review is wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

While looking at the Android review queue I saw [this submission](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/69342):

> [image: Context and it's use]

I was going to suggest that they fix the title, but looking further, I see this:

> [image: Fixed?]

Why is the title of the *suggestion* what's being reviewed? (Can I edit that suggestion to fix it's spelling mistake?)

Comment: The topic request had a mistake, while the proposal does not, right? In that case, there's no problem... The proposer is allowed to write their own title to satisfy a topic request, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/71880

Comment: @Frank The bug is that they chose a title, but the title that was shown in the queue was that of the topic request.

Comment: ..Oh, I see now.

Comment: Can I check; when you say "Android review queue", do you mean [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android?tab=proposedchanges)? Just so I'm looking at the same page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We now prefer the *draft* title to the *proposal* title in this list.

Comment: The real question is, why not title the proposal/draft using *its actual title*?

Comment: @CodyGray which is essentially what we're doing; in that queue, we're essentially listing drafts, so using the draft title is correct